# SSD vs HDD for high usage and long time use

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I was thinking of getting an SSD for my Video streaming laptop, but the specs say "endurance rating of up to 220TB total bytes written" does that me total bytes are written, then the drive is no good anymore?

My laptop records and streams audio/video 24/7 and in a half-hour, for example, will write 20 GB of data so will process 1+ TB of data read/writes a day, so I guess that means I will be replacing the SSD in less than a year, right? Better to stick with an HDD in my case, right? Thx

Comment: @Atralb - Your comment is extremely rude. Any additional rude commentary directed towards me will immediately be reported to a moderator.  Please don’t ping me with regards to 4 year old commentary.   Just report it as being unnecessary

Comment: @Atralb - You can tell me that I am wrong all day.  What I considered rude, was when you told me, I was the one who needed to do proper research.  Furthermore you replied to a 4 year old comment, you could have just flagged it, but instead you had to belittle me.  My original comment wasn't necessary ears old and it certainly wasn't necessary today which is the reason I deleted it.

Comment: @Atralb - My original comment shouldn't have been submitted.  However, that doesn't give you latitude, to be rude to me 4 years later. *I will politely ask you to stop attacking me.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Total Bytes Written (TBW) is an indication only and does not mean that the
disk cannot continue much beyond that value. The SSD has a large reserve of
replacement cells, and will normally enter a read-only state only when that
reserve is exhausted.

First false assumption :
Do not assume that 1 GB written to the disk equals 1 GB out of the TBW,
because large sector size may mean that the real value is up to 2-3 times that.

Second : Do not also assume that the TBW equation only includes data that you
write, since the SSD also constantly juggles data internally due to static data
rotation and garbage collection routines, so there is always a constant stream
of wear inside the SSD, even if you are not actively writing data to the drive.

The article [SSD Endurance Experiment](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead) has shown that good-quality
(and costly) SSDs may exceed their TBW by some petabytes, but that some
others may fail much sooner.

An SSD under such constraints as yours will need periodic checks of its
S.M.A.R.T data, and has better be scraped the moment write errors start
to appear. I also wouldn't count on the disk locking itself in read-only
mode without any data being lost, or on how much time it will take you to
understand what all those disk errors mean, since you will not get any
more meaningful messages from the operating system when the disk enters
read-only state (a system drive will then simply fail to boot).

It is impossible to predict the quality of your SSD.
Given your volume of writes, your SSD may last anything from 6 months
to a year, or 2-3 years if it is much better than its rating.
But I wouldn't advise you to plan on it.

In short, perhaps an SSD is not the best solution for your needs and
is too chancy, given your environment.

Comment: So since I wasn't planing on getting a high priced SSD off Amazon, guess I should just stick to HDD for my situation. Thx

Comment: Yes, cheap SSD's are really a false investment. Something like a Samsung EVO will last far longer. Even with HDD's though, don't assume they will last that long if you really are hammering them. Again don't buy cheap! If the HDD is always active, buy HDD's that are designed for it like a WD Red.

Comment: I agree as well. Better get a HDD that is rated as "enterprise". These are costlier but have typically a warranty period of 10 years which may make them more cost-effective than disks with shorter warranty.

Comment: @JulianKnight: A Samsung EVO is definitely toward the less expensive end of the range.

Comment: I may be out of the loop for buying SSD's :) The EVO's have a rep. for being about the best and most reliable SSD's available. Interestingly, their EVO SD cards are streets ahead of the competition for reliability too.

Comment: @JulianKnight: A lot of what's great about the EVO line is that they're about the best and most reliable available for roughly the same price as the bottom-of-the-barrel.  But they're definitely consumer class.

Comment: Whatever form of storage you pick, remember Duntemann's Law: "Anything you do not have backed up, you wiill eventually lose."

Comment: There is a Swedish 840/850 Evo SSD write torture test running http://gager.se/ssd/endurance/index.php; The 840 Evo is still running at 1925TBW where the 850 Evo died at 1000TBW.

Answer (score 2):

In a scenario like this, you really, *really* want two drives.  Check whether your laptop has an mSATA or m.2 slot where you can have a small SSD in addition to your larger HDD.

The reason is that video streaming is sequential access to very large amounts of data.  This isn't a problem for an SSD apart from the write endurance problem, but it is also the absolute best case for a rotating disk (keep it defragmented) because it can just write or read data continuously in a fixed order without having to seek.  Minimal head motion means no time wasted waiting for the seek, lower power consumption, lower heat, lower noise, longest life, best performance.  Inexpensive SSDs have little performance benefit over the sequential access performance of a modern HDD (> 100 MB/s).

The problem arises when you have a multitasking OS.  Some background task will want to access something other than the video, and then the continuous disk access is interrupted by the need to seek between the video and the other data.  This will cause the HDD performance to plummet, random access speeds are often < 0.1 MB/s.

If you get a lower capacity second disk (and because SSDs are physically smaller, a laptop is far more likely to have space for both SSD and HDD but not two HDDs), then the OS and applications can go on the SSD, and the HDD can be dedicated to the video streaming.  This will allow the HDD to operate almost exclusively with sequential access patterns (when the file size grows, updates have to be made to directory data as well as file contents, but video-processing applications should be smart about growing the output file in large chunks and infrequently).

Comment: Okay, thx for the info everyone.